# Cant install Laravel composer on Windows 10

Tags: laravel, composer-php, xdebug

I am currently trying to install the Laravel composer on Windows 10
but every time I do so get this message:

> The PHP exe file you specified did not run correctly:
> C:\xampp\php\php.exe
>
> Program Output: Xdebug: [Step Debug] Time-out connecting to debugging
> client, waited: 200 ms. Tried: localhost:9000 (through
> xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(

The php file path is correct.

I tried tinkering with the `php.ini` file and uncommented all the necessary extensions like those

> extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"
> extension=php_openssl.dll
> extension=php_ftp.dll
> zend_extension="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"

They are all uncommented but the composer won't install.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... remove all then reinstall

Comment: Why not disable XDebug? I don't think that this error is in any way related to Laravel itself

Comment: As per the error , your php is currupt, you should reinstall php. This has nothing to do with Laravel.

Comment: @NicoHaase thanks man that fixed it for me. i resorted to commenting the whole xdebug and uncommenting it after the install. thanks

Comment: The error message says that you have Xdebug INSTALLED and ENABLED already; and it's a Xdebug v3. It also tells that it is configured to try and debug every single script (or it sees "debug me" flag from somewhere, e.g. ENV variable). You can safely ignore that message (it's a Notice, not an Error) -- it is written to a console since your PHP's `error_log` config value does not seem to be pointing to the valid file and PHP (yes, PHP) writes it to the console.